# Postgres COPY to CSV

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to export a query to a `csv` file using the `COPY` command in `pgAdminIII`.

I'm using this command:

```
COPY (SELECT CASE WHEN cast(click as int) = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE -1
    END
    || ' '
    || id
    || '|'
    || 'hr_' || substring(hour, 7,8)
    --|| ' dw_x' + substring(datename(dw, substring(hour,1,6) ),1,2)
    || ' |dw_' || substring(to_char(to_date(substring(hour, 1,6),'YYMMDD'), 'dy'),1,2)
    || ' |C1_' || c1
    || ' |C21_' || c21
    || ' |C22_' || substring(to_char(to_date(substring(hour, 1,6),'YYMMDD'), 'dy'),1,2) || '_' || substring(hour, 7,8)
    AS COL1    
  FROM clickthru.train limit 10)     
  TO 'C:\me\train.csv' with csv;
```

When I run it I get:

```
ERROR: could not open file "C:\me\train.csv" for writing: Permission denied
SQL state: 42501
```

I then tried using the following in psql:

```
grant all privileges on train to public
```

and then look at access privileges using \z which returns :

[image]

but am still getting the same error.  I'm using postgresql 9.4 on a Windows 7 box.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`copy` writes the file under the user account of the Postgrs *server* process (it is a server side operation).

[From the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)

> *The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server*

Under Windows this is the system's "Network Account" by default.

Apparently that account does not have write privileges on that directory.

You have two possible ways of solving that:

1. change the privileges on the directory to allow everybody full access
2. use the client side `\copy` command (in `psql`) instead